# Syntax for three-piece segmented regression using NLS in R when concave

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, nls, piecewise

My goal is to fit a three-piece (i.e., two break-point) regression model to make predictions using propagate's `predictNLS` function, making sure to define knots as parameters, but my model formula seems off.

I've used the `segmented` package to estimate the breakpoint locations (used as starting values in NLS), but would like to keep my models in the NLS format, specifically, `nlsLM {minipack.lm}` because I am fitting other types of curves to my data using NLS, want to allow NLS to optimize the knot values, am sometimes using variable weights, and need to be able to easily calculate the Monte Carlo confidence intervals from `propagate`. Though I'm *very close* to having the right syntax for the formula, I'm not getting the expected/required behaviour near the breakpoint(s). The segments SHOULD meet directly at the breakpoints (without any jumps), but at least on this data, I'm getting a weird local minimum at the breakpoint (see plots below).

Below is an example of my data and general process. I believe my issue to be in the NLS formula.

```
library(minpack.lm)
library(segmented)

y <- c(-3.99448113, -3.82447011, -3.65447803, -3.48447030, -3.31447855, -3.14448753, -2.97447972, -2.80448401, -2.63448380, -2.46448069, -2.29448796, -2.12448912, -1.95448783, -1.78448797, -1.61448563, -1.44448719, -1.27448469, -1.10448651, -0.93448525, -0.76448637, -0.59448626, -0.42448586, -0.25448588, -0.08448548,  0.08551417,  0.25551393,  0.42551411,  0.59551395,  0.76551389,  0.93551398)

x <- c(61586.1711, 60330.5550, 54219.9925, 50927.5381, 48402.8700, 45661.9175, 37375.6023, 33249.1248, 30808.6131, 28378.6508, 22533.3782, 13901.0882, 11716.5669, 11004.7305, 10340.3429,  9587.7994,  8736.3200,  8372.1482,  8074.3709,  7788.1847,  7499.6721,  7204.3168,  6870.8192,  6413.0828,  5523.8097,  3961.6114,  3460.0913,  2907.8614, 2016.1158,   452.8841)


df<- data.frame(x,y)


#Use Segmented to get estimates for parameters with 2 breakpoints
my.seg2 <- segmented(lm(y ~ x, data = df), seg.Z = ~ x, npsi = 2)


#extract knot, intercept, and coefficient values to use as NLS start points
my.knot1 <- my.seg2$psi[1,2]
my.knot2 <- my.seg2$psi[2,2]
my.m_2 <- slope(my.seg2)$x[1,1]
my.b1 <- my.seg2$coefficients[[1]]
my.b2 <- my.seg2$coefficients[[2]]
my.b3 <- my.seg2$coefficients[[3]]

#Fit a NLS model to ~replicate segmented model. Presumably my model formula is where the problem lies
my.model <- nlsLM(y~m*x+b+(b2*(ifelse(x>=knot1&x<=knot2,1,0)*(x-knot1))+(b3*ifelse(x>knot2,1,0)*(x-knot2-knot1))),data=df, start = c(m = my.m_2, b = my.b1, b2 = my.b2, b3 = my.b3, knot1 = my.knot1, knot2 = my.knot2))
```

## How it *should* look

```
plot(my.seg2)
```

[image]

## How it *does* look

```
plot(x, y)
lines(x=x, y=predict(my.model), col='black', lty = 1, lwd = 1)
```

[image]

I was pretty sure I had it "right", but when the 95% confidence intervals are plotted with the line and prediction resolution (e.g., the density of x points) is increased, things seem *dramatically incorrect*.

[image]

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define g to be a grouping vector having the same length as x which takes on values 1, 2, 3 for the 3 sections of the X axis and create an nls model from these.  The resulting plot looks ok.

```
my.knots <- c(my.knot1, my.knot2)
g <- cut(x, c(-Inf, my.knots, Inf), label = FALSE)
fm <- nls(y ~ a[g] + b[g] * x, df, start = list(a = c(1, 1, 1), b = c(1, 1, 1)))

plot(y ~ x, df)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, df, col = "red")
```

(continued after graph)
[image: screenshot]

### Constraints

Although the above looks ok and may be sufficient it does not guarantee that the segments intersect at the knots. To do that we must impose the constraints that both sides are equal at the knots:

```
a[2] + b[2] * my.knots[1] = a[1] + b[1] * my.knots[1]
a[3] + b[3] * my.knots[2] = a[2] + b[2] * my.knots[2]
```

so

```
a[2] = a[1] + (b[1] - b[2]) * my.knots[1]
a[3] = a[2] + (b[2] - b[3]) * my.knots[2]
     = a[1] + (b[1] - b[2]) * my.knots[1] + (b[2] - b[3]) * my.knots[2]
```

giving:

```
# returns a vector of the three a values
avals <- function(a1, b) unname(cumsum(c(a1, -diff(b) * my.knots)))

fm2 <- nls(y ~ avals(a1, b)[g] + b[g] * x, df, start = list(a1 = 1, b = c(1, 1, 1)))
```

To get the three a values we can use:

```
co <- coef(fm2)
avals(co[1], co[-1])
```

To get the residual sum of squares:

```
deviance(fm2)
## [1] 0.193077
```

### Polynomial

Although it involves a large number of parameters, a polynomial fit could be used in place of the segmented linear regression.  A 12th degree polynomial involves 13 parameters but has a lower residual sum of squares than the segmented linear regression.  A lower degree could be used with corresponding increase in residual sum of squares.  A 7th degree polynomial involves 8 parameters and visually looks not too bad although it has a higher residual sum of squares.

```
fm12 <- nls(y ~ cbind(1, poly(x, 12)) %*% b, df, start = list(b = rep(1, 13)))

deviance(fm12)
## [1] 0.1899218
```

Comment: I think this is very nearly the answer I was looking for, but as written doesn't allow for the knots to be fit as parameters in the nls process. Nesting the assignment of g inside the formula e.g., `fm2 <- nls(y ~ a[cut(x, c(-Inf, c(knot1, knot2), Inf), label = FALSE)] + b[cut(x, c(-Inf, c(knot1, knot2), Inf), label = FALSE)] * x, df, start = list(a = c(1, 1, 1), b = c(1, 1, 1), knot1 = c(my.knot1, my.knot1, my.knot1), knot2 = c(my.knot2, my.knot2, my.knot2)))` gives me "Error in cut.default(x, c(-Inf, c(knot1, knot2), Inf), label = FALSE) : 
  'breaks' are not unique"

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. My issue is that by assigning g first, the grouping of x values is fixed according to the original estimated breakpoints (from segmented). Those are probably _close_ for most cases. But, I'd like to allow the breakpoints to be varied (and optimized) as needed (e.g., if the weighting regime in the NLS was changed). This should allow the propagation of the nls parameter uncertainty to my Monte Carlo simulation for confidence intervals. Any confusion in the question is entirely due to my writing.

Comment: The question applied segmented first so I was assuming you wanted a solution conditional on the knots from segmented and the main problem was the kink.

Comment: Indeed. I intended segmented as a preliminary step to get good "start" points for the nls. I'm suggesting this as the answer to the question as posed, though I'm still stuck on how to apply the numeric-to-factor step inside the nls formula.

Comment: OK. The question actually does state it wants to use segmented only as starting values but in any case I think that is likely to give rise to numerical problems shown there.

Comment: Have added a section on polynomial fit.

Answer (score 1):

It may, in part, reflect a limitation in `segmented`. `segmented` returns a single change point value without quantifying the associated uncertainty. Redoing the analysis using `mcp` which returns Bayesian posteriors, we see that the second change point is bimodally distributed:

```r
library(mcp)
model = list(
  y ~ 1 + x,  # Intercept + slope in first segment
  ~ 0 + x,  # Only slope changes in the next segments
  ~ 0 + x
)

# Fit it with a large number of samples and plot the change point posteriors
fit = mcp(model, data = data.frame(x, y), iter = 50000, adapt = 10000)
plot_pars(fit, regex_pars = "^cp*", type = "dens_overlay")
```

[image]

FYI, `mcp` can plot credible intervals as well (the red dashed lines):

```r
plot(fit, q_fit = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Jonas, your mcp package appears lovely. I did double-check the mean and std. error values for my breakpoints calculated from nls. Eye-balling from your plots above, the first breakpoint and error may not be far off (6102 ± 494.7); whereas the second one is much broader (11720 ± 3118).  St. Err for the original segmented model is way lower (342 and 195 respectively). Either way, recognizing the non-Gaussian distribution is certainly important.

Comment: I can see how the mcp package (and function) could be used to effectively replace nls or nlsLM (with propagate's predictNLS function) except that I don't see straightforward way to implement weights (i.e., weighted least squares) as in R's nls. Also, without fitting my own model, I'm not seeing an easy way to make predictions with confidence intervals in mcp. Or have I missed something important?

Comment: @m.s.bolton Yes, AFAIK, many frequentist methods tend to be overly optimistic as seen from Probability Theory (of which Bayesian Inference is an extension). I hope that the upcoming version of `mcp` will include weights and a `predict()` function, but it's not in the current CRAN version. It already does it internally when you plot a prediction interval, `plot(fit, q_predict = TRUE)`.

Comment: @m.s.bolton `mcp` 0.3 is on CRAN now. It supports weights (´model = list(y | weights(your_col) ~ 1 + x, ...)` and `fitted()` and `predict()`. Read more in the [changenotes](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/news/index.html)